# Afnetworking not parsing null properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

When I make a post request and null element is returned in the json, it is parsed into `"<null>"` instead of NSNull.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSURL * nsurl = [NSURL URLWithString:url relativeToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.baseUrl]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [manager.requestSerializer requestWithMethod:method URLString:[nsurl absoluteString] parameters:data error:nil];
AFHTTPRequestOperation * operation;
operation =   [manager HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request 
                    success: ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation , id responseObject){
                        if([[HEEnv env][@"debugLevel"] intValue]>0){
                            NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
                        }
                        [self parseFromJSON:responseObject];
                        completion(nil);
                    }
                    failure: ^( AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation , NSError *error){
                        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                        completion(error);
                    }
              ];
[manager.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
```

The response

```
JSON: {
"created_at" = "2014-02-18T19:58:46.000Z";
id = 1;
"is_new" = 0;
level = "<null>";
"topic_id" = "<null>";
"updated_at" = "2014-02-19T20:09:27.129Z";
xp = "<null>";
}
```

Comment: Huh? The log output shows `"<null>"`, not `@""`.

Comment: @rmaddy: That was a formatting problem in the question. `<...` is interpreted as HTML command if not quoted or escaped.

Comment: @MartinR I just realized that after your edit. Thanks.

Comment: "<null>" is just the display representation of `[NSNull null]` by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems to be only an artefact of the `NSDictionary` output. Example:

```
NSDictionary *d = @{@"key": [NSNull null]};
NSLog(@"%@", d);
```

Output:

```
{
    key = "<null>";
}
```

Accessing the values with `objectForKey` and comparing with `[NSNull null]` should
work without problems.